# ¿Cómo crear un sitio Web con ASPNET Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Quiero crear un nuevo sito web y no tengo la opción ni puedo agregar el comando de "Nuevo sitio web" (Archivo > Nuevo > Sitio Web...). Trabajo con Visual Studio Community 2017 15.6.6
Gracias.

Comment: Archivo>Nuevo>Proyecto y en la ventana que se te abre buscas el tipo de proyecto que te interesa. Arriba a la derecha un cuadro de búsqueda, si en éste pones directamente "web" puedes encontrar los "sitios Web" que puedes crear

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba empeñado en hacerlo como en las demás versiones. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Ahora debes ir a **Archivo -> Nuevo -> Proyecto..**

[image: Menú]

Dentro de los instalados elegís el lenguaje que vas a utilizar, lo desplegas y buscas **Web**

[image: Seleccionar Web]

Por último elegis el tipo de proyecto.

[image: Elegir tipo de proyecto.]

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede ayudar.

Usando La versión free de Visual Studio, "2017 Community"

Verifica el siguiente procedimiento:

1. Ve a > Archivo > Abrir > Sitio Web. ahora tienes a la vista la caja de dialogo "internet information Service local"
2. Verifica que la opción del panel derecho > IIS Local se encuentre seleccionada
3. Ahora ubícate en el panel central y pulsa sobre > Sitio de ISS Express
4. Ve a la barra de botones en la parte superior derecha y pulsa >  "Crear nuevo sitio". Te aparecerá en el árbol central de sitios > "WebSite1". Modifica su nombre si lo prefieres
5. Selecciona el nuevo sitio "WebSite1" y ahora ve nuevamente a la barra de botones en la parte superior derecha y pulsa > "Crear nueva aplicación web". Te aparece dentro del árbol > "WebSite". Modifica su nombre si lo prefieres.
6. Pulsa el botón > Abrir. Verifica en la ventana de Soluciones tu nuevo Site.

Copiado de Curso ASP.NET BÁSICO C#. Bases para Intermedio y Avanzados I,II por Cesar Castaño